# How to render nested square roots in html without using MathML?

Tags: html, css, math

I am trying to render an expression of the following kind using html and css.

```
SQRT(2 + SQRT(2 + SQRT(2)))
```

I cannot use MathML because it is not supported even in the latest versions of IE and Chrome. I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Here is the best I cam e up with, using the "radic" entity √ and text-decoration:overline, but I cannot figure out a way to render multiple overlines for the same line of html. I haven't tried positioning/layering though.

```
<span style="font-size:48px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2 + </span></span>
<span style="font-size:36px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2 + </span>   </span>
<span style="font-size:24px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2</span></span>
```

Nesting the SPANs is no better (in fact, it's worse) because then I end up just the outermost overline drawn on top of the whole expression.

Comment: Take a look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org).

Comment: I think nesting spans works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6tj5e/

Comment: Here's an example using MathJax: http://jsbin.com/uhevav/1/edit

Comment: have you consider using an image ?

Answer (score 2):

The way you're trying to make it work probably will be able to get it to work but I expect a very tedious process every time you have a new expression: my suggestion is to look at

- [mathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)
- [tex2png](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/tex2png/)

you really dont want to look at trying to do it purely in html/css. It will take you ages each time you have a new expression.

but if you do best I got is:

```
<span style="font-size:48px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2 + 
<span style="font-size:36px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2 +  
<span style="font-size:24px;">&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2</span></span>  </span></span></span></span>
```

after playing with the height a bit it will look alright.

Comment: I like your previous version (with `&radic;`) as it was more ASCII-compatible.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You are completely right, it accidently got changed during copying changed it back to the &radic;

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use mathjax : http://www.mathjax.org/

It has a great browser compatibility

Answer (score 1):

The following is in full conformance to the international standard on mathematical notations, ISO 80000-2:

√(2 + √(2 + √2))

This notation can be used even in plain text. If you want different rendering, using virgules for roots, it is best to use tools like MathJax.